# backgroundColor property of CupertinoPageScaffold

Tags: ios, flutter

There is a weird behaviour from my flutter app.
This a part of my code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Platform.isIOS
        ? CupertinoPageScaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
              middle: Text('MyShop', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ),
            child: GridView.builder(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                itemCount: pro.length,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10.0),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ProductsItems(
                    id: pro[index].id,
                    title: pro[index].title,
                    imageURL: pro[index].imageURL)),
          )
        : Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text('MyShop')),
            body: GridView.builder(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                itemCount: pro.length,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10.0),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ProductsItems(
                      id: pro[index].id,
                      title: pro[index].title,
                      imageURL: pro[index].imageURL,
                    )),
          );
  }
```

The problem is with the **backgroundColor** in **CupertinoNavigationBar** widget when that line is commented i get
[this as an output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFor4.png). **The navigation bar overlaps the pictures here**

but when include/uncomment that line as in the above code i get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGE7b.png)
which is what i want but can't understand why it is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the backgroundColor is omitted or set to Colors.transparent the NavigationBar gets translucent.
This is the **default behavior** of a CupertinoNavigationBar, when wrapped in a CupertinoPageScaffold.

As you have noticed, setting a color different from Colors.transparent makes the NavigationBar solid, creating the behavior you're looking for.

If you **don't want to change the backgroundColor** of the NavigationBar, you can either wrap the main content (body) of the screen in a **SafeArea** or use a Scaffold instead of CupertinoPageScaffold.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, Adding the SafeArea worked fine but could you explain more about "**setting a color different from Colors.transparent makes the NavigationBar solid**" what do you mean by makes it solid

Comment: By that I mean that the CupertinoNavigationBar is solid like a physical object, it takes up space in the layout. On the other hand when it's transparent it does not take up space, that's why the child of the CupertinoPageScaffold is partially below it and the CupertinoNavigationBar is just hovering over it.